# RecyclerView slowing when load mobile ads

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm using Different types RecyclerView. I created a view with them to load ads, the problem is when I try to scroll the RecyclerView it is so slow when loading the ad and after loaded it is working well. so I want to load the ad without slowing the scrolling in RecyclerView.

- I used **Handler** to wait for 5 seconds then load the ad, but it is also not working, and when the time is up the RecyclerView be slow.

  ```
            new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
            MobileAds.initialize(itemView.getContext(), initializationStatus -> {
            });
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            itemHomeAdBinding.adViewItemHome.loadAd(adRequest);
        }, 5000);
  ```
- I found some of the people here when I was searching for the solution suggest use NativeAds instead of BANNER, **SO I USED IT, BUT SAME PROBLEM HERE.**

  ```
            MobileAds.initialize(itemView.getContext());
        AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(itemView.getContext(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110")
                .forNativeAd(nativeAd -> {
                    NativeTemplateStyle styles = new NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().withMainBackgroundColor( new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.getContext(), R.color.card_color))).build();
                    itemHomeAdBinding.adViewItemHome.setStyles(styles);
                    itemHomeAdBinding.adViewItemHome.setNativeAd(nativeAd);
                })
                .build();
        adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
  ```

---

**So, any idea about how can I solve this problem?.**

- My ViewHolder for the ad

  ```
    static class AdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ItemHomeAdBinding itemHomeAdBinding;

    AdViewHolder(@NonNull ItemHomeAdBinding itemView) {
        super(itemView.getRoot());
        itemHomeAdBinding = itemView;
    }

    void setAdMob() {
        MobileAds.initialize(itemView.getContext());
        AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(itemView.getContext(), "ca-app-pub-8872798649235309/5921737523")
                .forNativeAd(nativeAd -> {
                    NativeTemplateStyle styles = new NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().withMainBackgroundColor( new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.getContext(), R.color.card_color))).build();
                    itemHomeAdBinding.adViewItemHome.setStyles(styles);
                    itemHomeAdBinding.adViewItemHome.setNativeAd(nativeAd);
                })
                .build();
        adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }

    void setOnClick(Ad ad) {
        itemHomeAdBinding.hadithText.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intents.INSTANCE.openUrl((AppCompatActivity) itemView.getContext(), Objects.requireNonNull(ad.getUrl()));
        });
        itemHomeAdBinding.firstImage.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intents.INSTANCE.openUrl((AppCompatActivity) itemView.getContext(), Objects.requireNonNull(ad.getUrl()));
        });
    }
  ```

  }
- And here I'm calling my ViewHolder in **onBindViewHolder**

  ```
        ................................ some code are here
    else if (getItemViewType(position) == R.id.adView_itemHome) {
        Ad ad = items.getAd().get(position - (items.getFirstItem().size() + 
                items.getKanzHasanat().size() + items.getCounter().size() + 
                items.getTahzeebMuslim().size()));
        ((AdViewHolder) holder).itemHomeAdBinding.setAdModel(ad);
        ((AdViewHolder) holder).setAdMob();
        ((AdViewHolder) holder).setOnClick(ad);

    } 
    ................................ some code are here
  ```